# How to get data from two databases via FastReport

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have created a report using FastReport Designer (Delphi 2010). I have one `TfrxIBXQuery (Query1)` connected with main database -`Base1(frxIBXComponents.DefaultDatabase:=Base1).` It works fine, I can get data using `Query1+MasterData` band.

The problem arises when I'm trying to get data from another database in the same report.
 In Designer I drop new `frxIBXDatabase (Base2)`, set the necessary properties. Add new `TfrxIBXQuery (Query2)` and connect it with Base2.
But I can't get any data from Query2 because it does not see Base2.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Menu: Report/Data are the Datasets visible and checked? Is the SQL valid for the second query?

Comment: @bummi Yes, I checked both. Have you ever managed to connect a second base in this way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with with firebird an usually working with ADO and datasets on datamodules, the described behavior using frxAdoDatabase and frxAdoQuery, in the report directly, with different connections for is only reproduceable with either an incorrect SQL or "unchecked" datasets.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the properties tab from your query component, can you see any FieldAliases?
If not, you should check the SQL, FastReport can be really picky when it comes to parameters.
Try changing parameter names and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use two or more databases inside report - you should use two TfrxIBXDatabase inside report (on the Data tab)
Clear frxIBXComponents.DefaultDatabase property